# Want to replace a specific word between 2 strings in linux file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I want to replace every `"<TD>" with "<TH>"` in every line of my file but only after `"<TD>Grand Total" to "</TABLE>"` keyword but not before `"<TD>Grand Total"` keyword with the help of bash script.

I tried below command but it is replacing the keyword in whole file. Please help me.

```
awk 'match($0,"<TD>Grand.*"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' myfile.txt | sed -i 's/TD/TH/g' myfile.txt
```

---

sample data is below

```
<br><br>Book Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>30</TD><TD>product2><TD>45</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>75</TD></TR></TABLE>

<br><br>Shoe Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>20</TD><TD>product2><TD>60</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>80</TD></TR></TABLE>

<br><br>Apparel Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>60</TD><TD>product2><TD>40</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>100</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

---

Required data sample is:

```
<br><br>Book Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>30</TD><TD>product2><TD>45</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>75</TH></TR></TABLE>

<br><br>Shoe Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>20</TD><TD>product2><TD>60</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>80</TH></TR></TABLE>

<br><br>Apparel Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>product</TH><TH>Quantity</TH></TR><TR><TD>product1><TD>60</TD><TD>product2><TD>40</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>100</TH></TR></TABLE>
```

[myfile.txt](https://dpaste.de/eKNg)

Comment: Can you give a sample input to make it more clear? A sample required output would also help.

Comment: Yes, you can check myfile.txt link

Comment: Try to post a question which follows http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated sample data here and required data sample also..

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester: I have already updated my try and sample data as well required data. Please let me know if you are getting anything missing, which will help me to get its solution..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the best answer but the following perl snippet should help:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (INPUTFILE, "mytext.txt") or die ("Unable to find the file");
open (OUTFILE, ">output") or die ("Unable to find the file");
my @lines = <INPUTFILE>;
foreach my $str (@lines) {
        if (my ($matches) = $str =~ /(<TD>Grand Total<\/TD>(<TD>-?[0-9.]+<\/TD>)*)/) {
                my $orig = $matches;
                $matches =~ tr/TD/TH/ ;
                $str =~ s/$orig/$matches/;
                print OUTFILE $str;
        }else{
                print OUTFILE $str;
        }

}
```

a new file 'output' should be created with the data you are looking for

Save the above a .pl file and execute it

Comment: Can I save above code in a .sh file and execute it..where I should update my filename suppose it is myfile.txt..it will be replaced with INPUTFILE or else. Please suggest.

Comment: Above is a perl code snippet. please replace "sample" with path to your file in the line : open (INPUTFILE, "sample") or die ("Unable to find the file");

Comment: edited code above as per your file name... copy the code and paste it into a file say replace_tag.pl .. and execute it by running 'perl replace_tag.pl'

Comment: thanks for your help it is working as I provided dummy example, but may you help me to get exact solution as it is changing "<TH>Grand Total</TH>" and tag just after it but my actual requirement is to change all tags after this to end of line..you can check actual file content in link as <myfile.txt>. Please help me.

Comment: one more thing that it is not copying heading (non mathing) rows like "<br><br>Book Inventory Report <br><br>" to output file.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant, Yes it is giving result same as required but where ever it is getting negative value like "<TD>-4</TD>" it is not converting, may you give its solution also.

Comment: Now negaitve nos. too should be handled... perhaps it should be good enuf for you to accept the solution or find it useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
sed -i.bak s/"Grand Total"/NEW_STRING/g myfile.txt
```

## edit

I've answer before you edit your question. In your case you can:

```
sed -i.bak s/"Grand Total\<\/TD\>\<\/TD\>"/"Grand Total\<\/TH\>\<\/TH\>"/g myfile.txt
sed -i.bak s/"\<\/TD\>\<\/TR\>\<\/TABLE\>"/"\<\/TH\>\<\/TR\>\<\/TABLE\>"/g myfile.txt
```

Comment: requirement is different...this will replace "Grand Total" to "new string" while I want to replace "TD" TO "TH" but only after "<TD>Grand Total"...

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your response..TD tag with grand total and with TABLE is easy to change but my problem is to change TD tags between them, those are variable as values will be changed between them as per result provided by mysql query.